# Creating multiple distinct path elements in D3JS

Tags: d3.js

Let us consider this simple data:

```
var data = [
    {
        "id": "A",
        "geometry": [ [0, 0], [10, 10], [10, 20], [0, 20] ]
    },
    {
        "id": "B",
        "geometry": [ [10, 10], [25, 10], [25, 30], [10, 20] ]
    },
];
```

I'd like to display "A" and "B" using a distinct area for each, as doing so will let me apply a class to them (useful because I want them to use different background colors and to react separately to clicks and mouse hovers.)

I'm able to use d3.svg.area() to draw a continuous graph however it assumes that "the input data is a two-element array of numbers" (not my case) and it does not seem to support the drawing of *distinct* areas.

What is the pattern for it?

**UPDATE**
I'm using polygons in the sample data for simplicity. Overall, the goal however is to produce a stream that be composed of several areas instead of just a single one. Best illustrated with the picture below:
[image: What I'm trying to achieve]

I'll update the post if more details are needed.

Comment: did you tried svg polygon in d3 ????

Comment: I've updated the question for clarity.

Comment: Could you simply apply `d3.svg.area` twice to the appropriately-formatted data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hard to understand what exactly you mean by wanting to draw distinct areas. Do you mean that you want to end up with 2 `path` elements –– one for the geometry of the object with `id:"A"` and the other for `id: "B"`? If so:

```
var pathGenerator = d3.svg.area()

var paths = d3.select("svg").selectAll("path").data(data);
paths.enter()
  .append("path")
  .attr("class", function(d) {
    if(d.id == "A") { return 'class-A'; }
    else if(d.id == "B") { return 'class-B'; }
  })
  .attr("d", function(d) {
    return pathGenerator(d.geometry);
  });
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I needed for simple polygons. You could simplify the "class" part like so: `.attr("class", function(d) { return "area " + d.id; })`