# Split stream (or path) into segments with D3JS

Tags: d3.js

Please consider this data:

```
var data = [];
    data.segments = [
                    { "id": "A", "start": 0, "end": 4}, 
                    { "id": "B", "start": 5, "end": 9}, 
                    { "id": "C", "start": 10, "end": 14},   
                ];
    data.stream = [
            [   0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                65, 60, 75, 85, 60,
                20, 30, 20, 25, 15,
            ],
            ];
```

I want to display it as three distinct parts, where the A segment (ie: the first 5 entries in the stream) would be red (or whatever the color), the B segment (the middle 5 entries) green and the C segment (the last 5 entries) blue.

Here's what it would look like with help from a photo-editing program:
[image: The desired outcome]

So far, I'm able to display `data.stream` as a [stream](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4254963). However, I'm stuck at breaking it into segments.

If my data was structured differently (as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19811428/creating-multiple-distinct-path-elements-in-d3js)), things would be easier. However, the way the data is structured right now is sort of ideal at it lets me separate the segment definitions from the stream data. This is useful as I want to be able to use different segments down the line. (You can look at those segments as sounds or words inside of an audio. Sometimes I would focus on individual sounds, sometimes on individual words, but the stream would always be the same.)

I put a working demo on JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/vsFhf/

**How can I color the different parts of the stream?**

Let me know if you need more details.

Thank you for the help-

Fabien

Comment: Do you want actual different elements or do you need just different colours?

Comment: In addition to the color for display, I need them to react separately to user input. So different elements really seems the way to go (then I can give them each a different id, class or what-not).

Comment: You have to do that yourself, i.e. provide the data that describes different parts of the stream as different objects. D3 doesn't provide anything to partition it automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No matter what, you still need individual `<path>` elements for each segment. You could construct a segmented data array as @ValarDohaeris suggests. But, you can also do it without transforming the data:

Instead of binding to `data.stream`, you need to bind to `data.segments`, which will enable you to create that one `<path>` per segment. Then you call `pathGenerator` for each of those `<paths>`, passing in a `slice` of the stream you're rendering `data.streams[0]`. You'll also need to X-translate each `<path>` to the appropriate position, using your `x` scale function.

[Here's the modified fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/meetamit/vsFhf/2/).

Answer (score 1):

Would it help to split the data according to your segment definitions?

```
var segmentdata = data.segments.map(function(segment, i) {
    return data.stream[0].slice(segment.start, segment.end + 1);
});
```

This will create:

```
segmentdata = [[0,0,0,0,0], [65,60,75,85,60], [20,30,20,25,15]]
```